# How to handle WhatsApp popup window by using WinAppDriver?

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, whatsapp, winappdriver, winapp

I'm trying to locate elements on popup WhatsApp window while calling. I see these elements in Inspector app, but can't focus at this window or locate any element. Is there a way to handle such type of popup windows?

[Inspect app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cWmwQ.jpg)

[Trying switch windows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AuUCA.jpg)

[Error switching windows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qC0uO.jpg)